# Insert image on index.php

Tags: php, image

I am trying to insert an image in the left column - just under the contact form - on my contact-page > http://sukhumvithd.com/index.php?ref=contact#.Ut9C17T-Icg

Code for Contact (index.php) https://www.dropbox.com/s/war41i1p355rsoe/index.php

I am new to this and have been playing around with different html and php tags.
I.e. This one:

```
<?php

    $image = "test_map.jpg";  
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';

    ?>
```

It won't show anything?! Seen out of the index code anything that blocks me from insert a simple image?

Any help/hints appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using an `<img>` tag? I don't know how you are using PHP, but if you are `echo`ing all of your HTML, you don't have to.

Comment: I did yes, but it just gave me the alternate-text.

Comment: The code that you posted makes no sense and has incorrect syntax at the same time. Why do you need to do it in php? why not add a simple html image tag such as <img src='images/myimage.jpg'/>?? please give more details if you want anybody to help you.

Comment: @ Yani. What code makes no sense? Just now it didn't show correctly. I tried with this: <?php

$image = "test_map.jpg";  
echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';

?> - Even the img src= ain't giving me anything but the alternate text. I don't have to do it in php. Is it possible that there is code somewhere that disables my tags?

Comment: Chances are the path you're using for the `src` attribute is incorrect